# Key is not present in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

table description

```
# \d invites;
                          Table "public.invites"
        Column         |       Type              |   Modifiers                       
-----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------
 id                    | integer                 | not null default 
 email                 | character varying       | 
 key                   | character varying       | 
 sender_user_id        | integer                 | not null
 receiver_user_id      | integer                     | 

Indexes:
    "invites_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_invites_receiver_user_id"
               FOREIGN KEY (receiver_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
    "fk_invites_sender_user_id"
               FOREIGN KEY (sender_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

you can see Foreighn Key **"fk_invites_receiver_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (receiver_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)**.
But the records for user with pk is absent in the parent table, where in the reference table fk is exists.

```
# select id from users where id = 958;
 id 
----
(0 rows)

select count(*) from invites where receiver_user_id = 958;
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

the question is how it can be, simple way to fix the conflicts is delete wrong records, but **want to exclude such situation in the future**, and when i try to restore the data there is an error:

```
DETAIL:  Key (receiver_user_id)=(958) is not present in table "users".
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY invites
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_invites_receiver_user_id
                   FOREIGN KEY (receiver_user_id) REFERENCES users(id);
```

P.S.

```
database=# select version();
                   version                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu,
 compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit
```

Comment: But, what is your question? Do you **really** want to allow non-existent FK values? What would they **mean** Do you want to fix them? Delete them? Insert the missing users into the users table?

Comment: i want clear(remove) noexisten FK, and be ensure that new failure will not created

Answer (score 1):

Create fail

```
-- tmp schema
-- \i tmp.sql

        -- tables
CREATE TABLE users
        (id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name text
        );
CREATE TABLE refs
        ( user_from INTEGER NOT NULL
        , user_to INTEGER NOT NULL
        , msg text
        );

        -- data
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('Alice'), ('Bob');
INSERT INTO refs VALUES (1,2), (1,3);

        -- FK constraints
ALTER TABLE refs
        ADD CONSTRAINT bad_user_from
        FOREIGN KEY (user_from) references users(id);
ALTER TABLE refs
        ADD CONSTRAINT bad_user_to
        FOREIGN KEY (user_to) references users(id)
        NOT VALID ; -- <<--HERE


        -- This should fail; user=3 does not exist
INSERT INTO refs VALUES (3,2), (2,3);
```

Repair

```
        -- "repair" the broken refs (by introducing a dummy row)
INSERT INTO users(id,name) VALUES (0, 'NoName');

        -- Make the bad FKs point to the dummy row
UPDATE refs r
SET user_to =0
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.id= r.user_to
        );

UPDATE refs r
SET user_from =0
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.id= r.user_from
        );

SELECT * FROM refs r
JOIN users u0 ON u0.id= r.user_from
JOIN users u1 ON u1.id= r.user_to
        ;

INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('NewName');
        -- see what we'v got
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT* FROM refs r
JOIN users u0 ON u0.id= r.user_from
JOIN users u1 ON u1.id= r.user_to;
```

Validate constraint

```
\d refs
\d users

        -- enforce the constraint
ALTER TABLE refs
        VALIDATE CONSTRAINT bad_user_to; -- <<-- HERE

        -- check if valid
\d refs
\d users

    -- This should not fail; user=3 does exist now
INSERT INTO refs VALUES (3,2), (2,3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.
Your solution is interesting and help me to know how to create bad FK, but, maybe I do not see, how i can create situations with valid FK and wrong values. I really interested how it can be.

Comment: That is exactly what the initial data demonstrates: `INSERT INTO refs VALUES (1,2), (1,3);` [user=3 does not exist at this time]

Comment: yes but if i try to do `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`  before `Make the bad FKs point to the dummy row` i catch the error `violates foreign key constraint`. But in the my base i do `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unfortunately “data corruption”.

You should delete the offending row, dump the database with `pg_dumpall` and restore it into a fresh cluster created with `initdb`.

You should also try to find out what caused the data corruption. Did you have any crashes recently? Could it be that you have unreliable storage or hardware problems? Anything weird in the database log?

To exclude such problems as much as possible, always use the latest fixpack for your PostgreSQL version and use reliable hardware.

Comment: thank you for the help, but i understand, that the "data corruption", and in the logs i not found something that can help me. So the question was create to find someone who may be seen the same in the database.

Comment: The question was "how it can be". Many people have seen data corruption like this. I once had something similar because I performed point-in-time-recovery with WAL from a database that had suffered from a hardware defect.

Comment: @BearBrown There is at least on bug fix in 9.4.16 that deals with data corruption. Does a `reindex` of the affected tables fix anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for comment we done next steps:
1. update postgres to `PostgreSQL 9.4.17`
2. `REINDEX` tables `invites` and `users`
3. `REINDEX` database, tried the steps with `export PGOPTIONS="-P"` but all invalid records still exists

Comment: Then it is table corruption, not index corruption. Delete all the rows in `invites` that have no match in `users`, like I suggested.

Comment: BTW: data corruption is not necessary, You can paint yourself into the corner by creating/adding the constraint as  `NOT VALID`

Comment: @wildplasser thank you for comment.
i test to create the FK with the option `NOT VALID` but in the table description i see it as not valid, in my case the constraint without it. example `"fk_t2_t1" FOREIGN KEY (t1id) REFERENCES t1(id) NOT VALID`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you, but i want to be ensure that new invalid records will not create, that is my point of research.

Comment: No invalid records were ever created, the database got corrupted by a) bad hardware or b) bad configuration (`fsync=off` or similar) or c) a PostgreSQL bug or d) manual manipulation of catalog tables.